# Character length SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I built a query (see below) however, instead of having a return of "greater than 20 or 30" I want my query to actually display the count (eg. 31, 35, 50, etc). I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Thanks for the help.

```
select
cc_units_of_measure.description as UOM_Description, 
 case when LEN(cc_units_of_measure.description) < 20 then 'OK' 
 else 'Greater than 20' 
 end as Results_UOM_description,
 cc_units_of_measure.company_abbreviation as UOM_Company_Abbreviation, 
 case when LEN(cc_units_of_measure.company_abbreviation) < 20 then 'OK'
 else 'Greater than 20' 
 end as Results_UOM_company_abbreviation,
cc_frequencies.description as Freq_Description, 
 case when LEN(cc_frequencies.description) < 30 then 'OK' 
else 'Greater than 30' 
end as Results_Frequency_description
from cc_units_of_measure, cc_frequencies
```

Comment: By count you mean the length of characters?

Comment: Try working from `select Sum( case when Len( cc_units_of_measure.description ) < 20 then 1 else 0 end ) as [UOM_LT20], ...`.

Comment: Is it length or count? In addition, your "else" should be "Equal or Greater than xx"

Comment: Just replace ‘Greater than X’ in else part with LEN(column name)?

Comment: To answer, is it length or count, I'm not sure now. The field "description" in the table "cc_frequencies", for example, cannot exceed 30 characters without creating issues in an application. So, I'm trying to create a script that will tell the installers what descriptions they need to edit to make the particular application work without errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the else part of the case statements to return the length you'll get the value you're looking for like so:

```
SELECT  cc_units_of_measure.description AS UOM_Description ,
        CASE WHEN LEN(cc_units_of_measure.description) < 20 THEN 'OK'
             ELSE LEN(cc_units_of_measure.description)
        END AS Results_UOM_description ,
        cc_units_of_measure.company_abbreviation AS UOM_Company_Abbreviation ,
        CASE WHEN LEN(cc_units_of_measure.company_abbreviation) < 20 THEN 'OK'
             ELSE LEN(cc_units_of_measure.company_abbreviation)
        END AS Results_UOM_company_abbreviation ,
        cc_frequencies.description AS Freq_Description ,
        CASE WHEN LEN(cc_frequencies.description) < 30 THEN 'OK'
             ELSE LEN(cc_frequencies.description)
        END AS Results_Frequency_description
FROM    cc_units_of_measure ,
        cc_frequencies
```

Comment: I tried this but ended up with an error: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'OK' to data type int.